# Filter on two arrays same time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have two arrays:

```
const array1 = [{
        "id": "4521",
        "name": "Tiruchirapalli",
        "stateId": "101"
      },
      {
        "id": "1850",
        "name": "Tenkasi",
        "stateId": "101"
      },
      {
        "id": "202",
        "name": "Thanjavur",
        "stateId": "101"
      },
      {
        "id": "505",
        "name": "Ernakulam",
        "stateId": "102"
      },
    ];
```

And now array2

```
 const array2 = [{
        "id": 1850,
        "cityName": "Tenkasi",
        "aliasNames": [
          "Thenkasi"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 4521,
        "cityName": "Tiruchirapalli",
        "aliasNames": [
          "Trichy"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 202,
        "cityName": "Thanjavur",
        "aliasNames": [
          "Tanjore"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 505,
        "cityName": "Ernakulam",
        "aliasNames": [
            "Kochi",
            "Cochin"
        ]
    },
    ];
```

what i need to do is, how to filter both the arrays at same time ( or filter first one and then second which ever one is performance effective ).

For instance, when user types "Kochi", first it should check on array1 to find if its has name="Kochi", if it has then we can set the state with that and if it doesnt have we need to find it on array2 and the update the state !

Which is fast and effective way to handle this - ( array1 has 2500 records and array2 has 990 records ) so performance / speed is also a concern

My attempt:

```
searchFilterFunction = text => {   
        this.setState({ typedText: text }); 
 
        const newData = array1.filter(item => {      
          const itemData = `${item.name.toUpperCase()}`;
           const textData = text.toUpperCase();
           return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;    
        });
        
        this.setState({ data: newData});  
      };
```

How to implement the second filter in optimized way ?

Comment: The best way I can think of is to loop thru the shorter array first and if you find the entry, you can set state and skip rest logic else you start filter on second array. In that case, time complexity would be O(n) where n is array1.length+array2.length

Comment: are you searching more than once. If yes, then you can create a map of names and this will save you time.

Answer (score 0):

> For instance, when user types "Kochi", first it should check on array1
> to find if its has name="Kochi", if it has then we can set the state
> with that and if it doesnt have we need to find it on array2 and the
> update the state !

I would do something like this with Array.find.

```
if( array1.find(item=>item.name.toUpperCase() === text) ) {    
   // set state 
} else if( array2.find(item=>item.cityName.toUpperCase() === text) ) {
   // set state
}
```

A refined form would be

```
let result = array1.find(item=>item.name.toUpperCase() === text);

// check in array 2 as we cannot find in array 1
if(!result) {
 result = array2.find(item=>{
     // check in aliasNames and in cityName
     return item.cityName.toUpperCase() === text  || item.aliasNames.includes(text);
   }
  );
}

if(result) {
  setState(result);
} else {
  // place not found
}
```

Regarding the performance based on your array count you will not see much difference. If you want to save some milliseconds you can check the array with least count first as mentioned in one of the comments. But the time also varies based on were the element is in array.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most optimal solution because nesting the two filter won't work as you need to filter from first array and then second.

```js
const array1 = [{
        "id": "4521",
        "name": "Tiruchirapalli",
        "stateId": "101"
      },
      {
        "id": "1850",
        "name": "Tenkasi",
        "stateId": "101"
      },
      {
        "id": "202",
        "name": "Thanjavur",
        "stateId": "101"
      },
      {
        "id": "505",
        "name": "Ernakulam",
        "stateId": "102"
      },
    ];

 const array2 = [{ "id": 1850, "cityName": "Tenkasi",
        "aliasNames": [
          "Thenkasi"
        ]
      },{"id": 4521,"cityName": "Tiruchirapalli",
        "aliasNames": [
          "Trichy"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 202,
        "cityName": "Thanjavur",
        "aliasNames": [
          "Tanjore"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 505,
        "cityName": "Ernakulam",
        "aliasNames": [
            "Kochi",
            "Cochin"
        ]
    },
    ];


function filter(text) {
// Complexity Linear
  const filter_array = array1.filter((a) => {
      return (a.name === text)
  });
  if (filter_array.length > 0) {
    //Set State and return
  } 
  
  //Complexity Linear and includes complexity Linear O(sq(m*n)) where n is     //the aliasName record 
  const filter_array2 = array2.filter((a) => {
    return a.cityName === text  || a.aliasNames.includes(text);
  });
  return filter_array2 //Set State filter array 2
  
}

console.log(filter("Kochi"));
```